# Limiting data in a crosstab query on MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot, aggregate-functions, crosstab

I recently got help with this question:

[MySQL Crosstab / Pivot Aggregation. Removing counts based on column in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014699/mysql-crosstab-pivot-aggrigation-removing-counts-based-on-column-in-other-tab)

Where I was attempting to filter out crosstab counts based on a string being present in another table.

Now I'm trying to filter the results further, this time by date.

What I'm trying to do is only count the last car of a particular Make_Model, Color and Year added on each day.

For example, if I added a 2015 Black Ford Fusion at 12:15PM on 05/11/2016 and another one at 1:33PM that same day, I only want to count the one at 1:33PM in the crosstab.

**THE DATA**

I've changed my data a bit, to account for the new info:

```
CAR_INVENTORY TABLE
CAR_ID  MAKE_MODEL      COLOR   YEAR    DATE_ADDED
1       Ford Fusion     Black   2015    2016-05-11 11:25:00
2       Tesla Model S   White   2014    2016-05-11 11:25:00
3       Acura ILX       Blue    2013    2016-05-11 11:25:00
4       Ford Fusion     Black   2013    2016-05-11 11:25:00
5       Toyota Corolla  Blue    2014    2016-05-11 11:25:00
6       Ford Fusion     Blue    2013    2016-05-11 11:25:00
7       Toyota Corolla  Blue    2012    2016-05-11 11:25:00
8       Acura ILX       Black   2015    2016-05-11 11:25:00
9       Ford Focus      Blue    2012    2016-05-11 11:25:00
10      Ford Fusion     White   2013    2016-05-11 11:25:00
11      Acura ILX       Black   2012    2016-05-11 11:25:00
12      Toyota Corolla  Black   2015    2016-05-11 11:25:00
13      Toyota Corolla  Blue    2014    2016-05-11 11:37:00
14      Ford Focus      White   2015    2016-05-11 11:25:00
15      Tesla Model S   Red     2015    2016-05-11 11:25:00
16      Acura TLX       White   2014    2016-05-11 11:25:00
17      Toyota Corolla  Blue    2014    2016-04-11 12:43:33
18      Ford Focus      Black   2013    2016-05-11 11:25:00
19      Ford Focus      White   2015    2016-05-11 14:29:12


INVENTORY_LOG TABLE
LOG_ID  CAR_ID  NOTE
1       7       Issue with Fuel Guage
2       3       Sweet Ride
3       16      Zippy
4       14      Issue with transmission
5       3       Fun to Drive
6       2       *NULL*
7       8       *NULL*
8       10      Economic
9       15      WOW
10      9       Good Fuel Economy
11      16      Minor issue with Shifting
12      7       Issue with Airbag
13      17      Great Mileage
14      1       Nice Tech
15      13      *NULL*
16      11      Trunk is small
17      12      *NULL*
18      2       Very Speedy
19      7       Good Mileage
20      10      Roomy
21      4       *NULL*
22      6       Nice Tech Package
23      5       Good Economy
24      18      Cool
25      19      Nice ride, but bad fuel econ
```

Here's what I'm trying to get:

```
DESIRED RESULT
MAKE            Black   Blue    White   
Acura           1       1       0
Ford            3       1       2
Tesla           0       0       1
Toyota          1       2       0
```

With the following four cars removed:

```
DUE TO ISSUES:
car_id  car                         issues
7       2012 Blue Toyota Corolla    2
14      2015 White Ford Focus       1
16      2014 White Acura TLX        1

DUE TO TIMESTAMP:
car_id  car
5       2014 Blue Toyota Corolla (car_id 13 is later)
14      2015 White Ford Focus* (car_id 19 is later)
*also had issue

Note we're also not counting the red one, as It's not in the cross tab.
```

The car_inventory table has one row for each car in stock.  The inventory_log table has at least one entry for each car listed in car_inventory, so each car may have many log entries.  The entries in inventory_log can be null.

---

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**

Thanks to some help on my previous question, I've come up with the following query to generate the crosstab, and remove cars with 'issues'.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ci.make_model LIKE "Acura%" THEN "Acura"
        WHEN ci.make_model LIKE "Ford%" THEN "Ford"
        WHEN ci.make_model LIKE "Toyota%" THEN "Toyota"
        WHEN ci.make_model LIKE "Tesla%" THEN "Tesla"
    END AS Make,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ci.color = "Black" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Black,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ci.color = "Blue" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Blue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ci.color = "White" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as White
FROM car_inventory ci
WHERE 
    (ci.year > 2012) AND
    (ci.car_id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT il.car_id 
        FROM inventory_log il 
        WHERE il.note LIKE '%issue%'
    ))
GROUP BY Make
ORDER BY Make;
```

I've also worked out this query:

```
SELECT
    ci.car_id
FROM
    car_inventory ci
GROUP BY
    ci.make_model,
    ci.color,
    ci.year,
    DATE(ci.date_added)
ORDER BY
    ci.car_id;
```

Which does limit what's returned to one car_id per day for each make_model, color and year.  However, it's returning the earliest car_id added, not the latest.  Once I have that, I can probably use another subquery.

**QUESTION**

1. How do I limit what's being selected to so that it returns only one car_id per day (per make_model, year, color combo), and only the latest one for each day.
2. How do I work that into my crosstab query.  Can I just add another subquery to the where clause like `AND (ci.car_id IN (SELECT ...)` ?  Is having so many subqueries bad for performance?
3. Is there a better way to do it with a join or some other structure?  Same question for my original subquery.

Comment: A better way? Well, I think so. I think issues of data display are best resolved in application level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting on an ordered array). Aside from that, it's certainly odd to store make and model as a single entity

Comment: I know my data is not normalized... let's assume I can't change that.

My schema here is only a sample.  My actual data is much more complex, and I've boiled it down for simplicity, and to hide details about what I'm working on that my client might not want revealed.

Comment: @Strawberry the problem with doing it in PHP (in my case) is there's too much data to transfer over to PHP before this filtering can be done.  On the order of millions of records.

For speed, I need to have it done in MySQL.

Comment: Why does it matter whether it counts the max or the min car id per day? You are only counting. Btw if you replaced car_id with max(car_id) in the select list of the subquery, you would get the latest one.

Comment: @Shadow In my real data, I have a use case where this matters.  Were I to attempt to explain or model that use case, this question would be unnecessarily complex.  Let's just say that in my actual use case, I'll have additional columns that I'll need to filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting the exact counts you're expecting in but this might help

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Acura%' THEN 'Acura'
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Ford%' THEN 'Ford'
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Toyota%' THEN 'Toyota'
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Tesla%' THEN 'Tesla'
        END AS Make,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ci.color = 'Black' THEN ci.COUNT ELSE 0 END) as Black,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ci.color = 'Blue' THEN ci.COUNT ELSE 0 END) as Blue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ci.color = 'White' THEN ci.COUNT ELSE 0 END) as White
FROM    (-- GET DISTINCT COUNTS
         SELECT ci.MAKE_MODEL,
                ci.COLOR,
                ci.YEAR,
                DATE(ci.DATE_ADDED) AS DATE,
                COUNT(DISTINCT MAKE_MODEL) AS COUNT
         FROM   CAR_INVENTORY ci
         WHERE  YEAR > 2012
                AND CAR_ID NOT IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT il.car_id 
                    FROM inventory_log il 
                    WHERE il.note LIKE '%issue%'
                )
         GROUP BY ci.MAKE_MODEL,
                ci.COLOR,
                ci.YEAR,
                DATE(DATE_ADDED)
        ) ci
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Acura%' THEN 'Acura'
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Ford%' THEN 'Ford'
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Toyota%' THEN 'Toyota'
            WHEN MAKE_MODEL LIKE 'Tesla%' THEN 'Tesla'
        END

Result:
Make   Black       Blue        White
------ ----------- ----------- -----------
Acura  1           1           0
Ford   3           1           2
Tesla  0           0           1
Toyota 1           2           0
```

I'm only getting 1 for Acura Black because there are only 2 and 1 is a 2012

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58fea/8)

Comment: Actually, I believe your counts add up.  I had an error in my manual counts above (now corrected).  Let me test a couple more things, and I'll accept your answer.  Any comments on my other questions about subquery performance or a Join only way of doing this?

Comment: I dont think your suquery is bad.. You "might" get better performance using NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN.. that would looks like this `WHERE YEAR > 2012 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inventory_log il WHERE il.car_id = ci.car_id AND il.note LIKE '%issue%')`